# "Cripple" specific LESS imports when importing e.g. Bootstrap

Tags: node.js, gulp, less

When @importing `bootstrap.less` into my main file, I'd like to skip importing a few files (like glyphicons).

Instead of copying (or boo, hiss, *modifying*) the `bootstrap.less` I'd like to specify something like `@cripple-import 'bower_components/bootstrap/less/glyphicons.less';` before my `@import 'bootstrap.less';` in order to make that specific import noop.

Is there a Less plugin for this, or is it supported OOTB?

Comment: There's no dedicated feature (as this is more up to a library design rather than yet another bloating a language with kludge feature to abuse existing libraries). You can however abuse the default `@import (once)` behaviour. I.e. if you import either file before `bootstrap.less` (e.g. `.skipme() {@import: 'glyphicons.less';}` so that it won't generate any CSS), further imports will be ignored.

Comment: In general though, there's *nothing* wrong with having your own modified copy of `bootstrap.less` - as it's nothing but a list of components you need to compile (thus "not modifiying library files" is never a self-goal, but a clear/easy maintenance is - so in this particular case having your own explicit list of components you want is the winner).

Comment: @seven-phases-max You know how to do this in SCSS?

Comment: @seven-phases-max I do have to disagree in the case of TWBS however, there are many wierd interdependencies between the individual LESS files. That's partly also why it's so hard to upgrade a Bootstrap site where the Bootstrap code is interweaved with your own code.

Answer (score 1):

As @seven-phases-max seems to have better things to do, I'll write the answer myself.

The following code works swell:

```
.cripple-imports() {
    @import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/glyphicons.less";
    @import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/panels.less";
    @import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/carousel.less";
    @import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/list-group.less";
    @import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/tooltip.less";
    @import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/progress-bars.less";
    @import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/code.less";
    @import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/badges.less";
    @import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/jumbotron.less";
    @import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/thumbnails.less";
    @import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/wells.less";
}

@import "../Vendor/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
```

Comment: For Sass, you have no such option though. You need to stop using @include directly, and instead utilize some kind of custom mixin.